# Android - Change View when alertdialog button is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a listview with a couple of strings in at the moment. when a user selects one it brings up an alertdialog box which gives the option to book(this is going to be a taxi app) or cancel. What i cant work out is how to get it so that when the user clicks "Book" it takes the information they've selected and loads up a new view with more contact information.

My Code is currently this -

public class ListTaxi extends ListActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    String[] taxi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listtaxi, taxi));

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
       {   
           AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListTaxi.this); 
           adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
           adb.setMessage("You have chosen = "+lv.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
          adb.setPositiveButton("Book", null);
          adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
          adb.show(); 
       } 
 });
```

Any help or pointers with this would be immensely appreciated as its the last bit i need to get working before its almost done.

Thanks everyone

Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put an `onClickListener` onto your positive button, which will launch the new activity and pass the data to it.  Your code would become something like:

```
public class ListTaxi extends ListActivity{ /** Called when the activity is first created. */ public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String[] taxi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listtaxi, taxi));

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
    {   
        final int selectedPosition = position;
        AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListTaxi.this); 
        adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
        adb.setMessage("You have chosen = "+lv.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
        adb.setPositiveButton("Book", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("booking",  taxi[selectedPosition];
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
        adb.show(); 
    }
});
```

In your target activity, have something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String booking = "";
if (intent != null) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        booking = extras.getString("booking");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for this! looks like solid coding. Quick question if i may, ive put the code in and changed the next activity to my class to which its going. It seems to keep coming up with errors when i create a new intent?

Comment: oops forgot this - code below Intent intent = new Intent(this, Booking.class);
                        intent.putExtra("booking",  lv.getItemAtPosition(position));

Comment: ah, `getItemAtPosition(position)` is going to return an `Object`, so you will need to get your appropriate value from the `Object` and pass that into `putExtra`

Comment: alternatively, I think you could replace `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)` with `taxi[position]`

Comment: its the intent bit that i cant seem to get right. the other bit seems to tick along nicely, keeps getting an error at  new Intent(this, Booking.class);

Comment: ah yes, its the reference to `this`, I've updated the code above to use `getApplicationContext()` instead.  You may also need to make your `taxi` array final to access it within the `onClick` method

Comment: ah wicked! and then i assume i just call it in booking.java using the intent command?

Comment: yes, I've added some sample code for the target activity above

Comment: thanks this is awesome! one more bit and i promise ill leave you be lol. im calling a textview to display the item selected but i cant get it register the string. any ideas?

Comment: If your original issue is now working, I think you should probably raise a new question for the new problem.  Myself or someone else will then be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to get your item out of your taxi list:

```
taxi.get(position);
```

and pass it through an intent to a next activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_NEXT_ACTIVITY.class);    
intent.putExtra("booking",  taxi.get(position);
```

on the next activity you can get it with:

```
intent = getIntent();
inten.getExtra("booking");
// could be (not sure): inten.getExtraString("booking");
```

Comment: thank you! ill have a play and get back to you. you are my favourite person at this point in time!

Comment: how would i call it from the next activity? i cant get it to recognize the intent method bit. Cheers

Comment: call what? the intent?
a good way is also start an activity for result... tell me if u r interessted... i can post an example

Comment: well basically, ive got the alertdialog box to take me to the next activity. now im trying to work out how to display the info that ive just clicked on the new page. if that makes sense? so user clicks listview item-item pops up in dialog box saying book or cancel? - user clicks book and then info displays on next screen.

Comment: u put your information into the intent which will start your next activity with : intent.putExtra("booking",  taxi.get(position); _ Then on the other activity you retrieve the intent with: Intent myIntent = getIntent();
with Sting s = myIntent.getStringExtra("booking"); you will get your String value... (try with autocompletion don't know if "getStringExtra" is spelled correctly). Are you looking for this?

Comment: ah i get you. im just working out a way to display it on the next screen. So that code should take the item selected and put it into the String S? How could i display that text ? an edittext box or something?

Comment: Yes it'll be in String s and then just use it the normal way e.g.: I would suggest a **TextView**... Did you define a own layout via XML? If yes add a **TextView** and get it with: **TextView tv_taxi** = (TextView) v
     .findViewById(R.id.textview_taxi);** _ In case you didn't and want to do it, keep all letters of the xml-file-name lowercase, otherwise you'll get an error... then **tv_taxi.setText(s)**

Comment: yeah i have got my own xml. at the moment i have - 
public class Booking extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.booking);

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String booking = "";
         if (intent != null) {
             Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
             if (extras != null) {
                 booking = extras.getString("booking");
       
                  
                 
           }   
             }
         }

Comment: and my xml is <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtaxi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="" />

i think thats what im supposed to have?

Comment: Looks good... But as far as I understood you, what you need it does look good. But I think you don't need the **Bundle**, at least I'm doing it without ;)
Ohh wait, should it be **String s = intent.getStringExtra("booking");** _ You are actually misssing the **"Extra"** on the method.  
Does it work now?

Comment: @Oli u could have given dave.c and me at least a "useful answer" click... after working with u though it <.<

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method from alertDialog class

```
public void setButton (int whichButton, CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

Refer link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html
depending on positive response, say book is positive response then start another activity which shows details contact info, pass the select item from list as Bundle or extra with intent while starting another activity.