# Android - Displaying ListView item in a textview

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-alertdialog

I have managed to setup a page so that a user clicks an item in a listview which then shows an alertdialog box and gives them the option to book or cancel. If they click book it takes them to another screen. What i need is to show the item selected on the next screen. I almost have it but i cant work out where its going wrong. What i was hoping is if someone could help in working out the best way to do this?

My code at present is -

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id)
       {   
            final int selectedPosition = position;
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListTaxi.this); 
             adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
             adb.setMessage("You have chosen = "+lv.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
             adb.setPositiveButton("Book", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Booking.class);
                     intent.putExtra("booking",  taxi[selectedPosition]);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });
             adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
             adb.show(); 
         }
     });
```

And on the booking.java is:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.booking);
            TextView tv_taxi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtaxi);
            //tv_taxi.setText(taxi);

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String booking = "";
        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                booking = extras.getString("booking");   

            }


            }

        }
```

Original article is at - [Android - Change View when alertdialog button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584668/android-change-view-when-alertdialog-button-is-clicked)

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the text on your `TextView` to be the value you retrieved from the `Bundle`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.booking);
    TextView tv_taxi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtaxi);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String booking = "";
    if (intent != null) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            booking = extras.getString("booking");
            tv_taxi.setText(booking);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have no idea how much of a legend you are! Thanks Dude